# Permission denied: docker-machine create

Tags: docker

I want to set up a swarm cluster consisting of 2 nodes, but when I run the code:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --swarm --swarm-master --swarm-discovery token://<clusterid>
```

in order to create a swarm master, I receive the following message:

> -bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-machine: Permission denied

Trying the same code with sudo also produces:

> sudo: docker-machine: command not found

How do I fix this?

Comment: How about running it with  `sudo -s command`?

Comment: Instead of using the docker-machine to create the swarm manager, i used the: docker run -d -p <swarm port>:2375 swarm manage token://<clusterid> and the swarm manager has been created. I will now add the nodes to the cluster. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

Fix it?

(Might need `sudo`)