# Curl command to install docker-machine and/or docker-compose does not work in Ubuntu Xenial

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-machine

I just installed docker-machine with [these instructions](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/). When I try `docker-machine version` I get no output and no error message. I have already made the file executable as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228127/permission-denied-docker-machine-create). Basically my terminal looks like this:

```
$ docker-machine version
$ docker-machine help
$ _
```

I'm on an almost new install of Ubuntu Xenial. I had the same problem with docker-compose but the fix there was to use a virtual env and do a `pip install`. I don't see that available for docker-machine.

How do I troubleshoot this when it's not giving me an error message or output of any kind?

---

EDIT #1

This turned out to be irrelevant.

---

EDIT #2

This turned out to be irrelevant.

---

EDIT #3

Actually I definitely overlooked something here. This is the output from the [install command](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/).

```
$ curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.7.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/usr/local/bin/docker-machine
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
```

Now looking at what is in this path `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`.

---

EDIT #4

My problem was with `curl`. It was looking for `ssl` files in the wrong place. The fix is found in the [ubuntu forums](https://askubuntu.com/a/733550).

Comment: What is the exit status (run `echo $?` after running a `docker-machine` command)? Have you checked any system logs like syslog and dmesg? Smells like some other underlying security of the OS stopping the binary from running (AppArmor?).

Comment: You should try `docker-machine --version` and `docker-machine --help`.

Comment: @AndyShinn `docker-machine help` followed by `echo $?` gives me `0`. I've never looked into system logs before but I'll try that now. I'll edit the post once I find the relevant output.

@warmoverflow I tried the `--` prefix but it makes no difference.

Comment: Now that this is fixed, how should I edit this question? I changed the title and removed irrelevant things from my edits. Is there any other etiquette I should follow? Should I answer my own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: This is a copy of an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/733550/540951) in the Ubuntu Forums. The author is [Yahya Uddin](https://askubuntu.com/users/449068/yahya-uddin). It fixed my problem.

---

Simply create a `~/.curlrc file`.

Then add the following lines to the file:

```
capath=/etc/ssl/certs/
cacert=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Feel free to adjust those paths as necessary, as different Linux distributions may use different paths.

(Worked for Ubuntu 16.04).